# Linear Algebra free variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have started taking a basic course in linear algebra and have a doubt.
I understand that in order to know if AX=B Has solutions and how many of them..first we modify the matrix to its echelon form.
I am told the **number of columns free of pivots = number of free variable.**

Even after giving thought to this..i cant reason this out..Any help would be much apppreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have trouble understanding why the number of columns free of pivot variables equals number of free variables.. Ie how can we assume arbitrary value to the variable corresponding to those columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing a matrix to echelon form, we can see that a column is either a pivot column or a non-pivot column.

A system of linear equations corresponds to $Ax=b$. In a linear system are two types of variables: basic or free. The basic variables are determined by the pivot positions of $A$, whilst free variables are determined by the non-pivot positions of $A$.

For example, suppose we are given the equation $Ax=b$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$, $b=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$. Notice that $A$ is in echelon form, and the equation $Ax=b$ is equivalent to:

$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{1} & 0 & \color{blue}{5} \\ 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

and is equivalent to the system of linear equations:

$$\begin{align}\color{red}{x_1}+0x_2+\color{blue}{5x_3}&=b_1\\
0x_1+\color{red}{x_2}+\color{blue}{(-2)x_3}&=b_2\end{align}$$

The correspondence of the pivot positions to basic variables are in red and of non-pivot positions to free variables are in blue.

The solution to this system is given by $x_1=-5x_3, x_2=2x_3$, and a free variable $x_3$. Since we have a free variable, this system of linear equation has infinitely many solution since we can always find an $x_3$ that will satisfy the equation, and since the free variable corresponds to the non-pivot positions of $A$, hence we can place any value there as well that will satisfy the matrix equation.

(Also remember that a system of linear equation either has no solution, one solution, or infinitely many solutions).

Comment: I assume in matrix a in the beginning a23 was minus 2? Or have you performed any operation afterwards

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan Yup that was typo fixed

Comment: Great answer..thanks mate :)

Comment: The same applies when the b is non zero?

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan yes, I changed it since it actually addresses the question.

Comment: Shouldn't $x_1 = b_1 - 5x_3$ and $x_2 = b_2 + 2x_3$? If we were solving $A\vec{x} = 0$, then it would be correct.

Comment: I second rb612's comment.